# Detect Session Expiry in Asp.Net MVC 5 Razor Application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am developing Asp.Net MVC 5 Razor Application. I am maintaining separate table to maintain login information. When user logs in, I put 'true' in a field (IsLoggedIn) on success callback of login, in that table. When user logs out, I put 'false' in that field on success callback of logout module.

I am having one problem. If user does not press log out button, and its session is expired it gets log out. My success callback of logout is not called and 'IsLoggedIn' field in database still shows true for that user.

I am unable to find anything regarding how can I detect session expiry event and call my table updation function to put 'false' in 'IsLoggedIn' field to for user row?

Any Help?

Comment: which sessionstate mode are you using ?

Comment: There is nothing like that in my web.config.

Comment: you are not seeing anything like <sessionState mode=" ... "> in web.config ?

Comment: if you are not seeing anything like sessionstatemode in web.config file, your application uses inproc sessionstate mode as default.

Comment: How can I detect session expiry for any user session?

Comment: See my answer below for further help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session timeouts can be handled in the Session_End event in your Global.asax, if your application using InProc SessionState mode(this is default in ASP.net if not specified)

```
void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // perform your logic
}
```

before doing this remember one thing The event will be called, but not necessarily right after the timeout.

also take this into consideration that [According to MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout.aspx),the HttpSessionState.Timeout property has a setter and can be changed from within your application's code as well as permanently in the web.config

Hope this helps

Comment: Great. It detects the session end, but HttpContext.Request.Cookies is not available in Session_End method.

Comment: what you need to do with cookies in session End event?

Comment: My session details like, user name and sessionId are saved in cookies.
HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionIDRequest.Cookies["LoginDetail"]

Comment: what about using this.Context.Request.Cookies to get the cookie collection ?

Comment: I want get values from cookies and update the table with 'IsLoggedIn' false.

Comment: this.Context.Request.Cookies is not available in Global.asax.

Comment: i think you can store that information on the session itself because Httpcontext is not avaialble in Sesssion_End Event.please refer this link for more information on session and httpcontext http://forums.asp.net/post/7504.aspx